# Which one is best to use as performance wise: Service chaining or Callout midiator in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created a service, which internally calls some other service.

Now in some situation, I am thinking to use callout mediator. But someone told me that Callout Mediator is not good as performance point of view.

So I need your suggestion that what should I use, service chaining or Callout mediator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide based on your Scenario.

If you want your service calls to be blocked, then you can go with `Callout` Mediator or else if you need chained invocation, you can go with `ServiceChaining`

The link will explains you clearly,
http://supunk.blogspot.in/2010/06/difference-between-service-chaining-and.html

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi Ramya,  Thanks for your reply :) actually I have used DBLookup mediator in my service but now requirement is changed and need to use a stored procedure... I believe dblookup/dbreport does not support you to use return type parameter in stored procedure.. and now I am thinking to create service in DSS for this. I don't want to break my code flow so thinking to use callout mediator for DSS which will keep my code flow remain same.. but some one told me that service chaining is more efficient that call out mediator... if callout does not impact performance that I will go with that.

Comment: If my answer is useful, you can upvote my answer :-)

Comment: Do you have any example which fulfill my requirement for this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793428/not-getting-out-parameter-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-wso2-esb-dblookup... I have liked your post @FB :-)

Comment: no issue.. Thanks brother for your help.. god bless :)